# Creating a named route for a controller with static actions using Rails 3 routing API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a basic controller with named actions representing static pages:

```
class YourTripController < ApplicationController
  def when_to_visit
  end

  def booking_a_trip
  end

  ...

end
```

I want a named route to access these actions like:

```
your_trip_path(:when_to_visit)

your_trip_path(:booking_a_trip)
```

Seems simple enough right? But I also want to have the URLs use dashs rather then underscores for the generated paths:

example.com/your-trip/when-to-visit
example.com/your-trip/booking-a-trip

Given these constraints what does my route/s look like?

I've tried many approaches and this is the closest I've got so far:

```
  controller :your_trip, :path => 'your-trip', :as => :your_trip do
    get "when_to_visit", :path => 'when-to-visit'
    get "booking_a_trip", :path => 'booking-a-trip'
  end
```

This correctly routes me to the right action but using a url helper such as your_trip_path(:when_to_visit) results in:

No route matches {:action=>"when_to_visit", :controller=>"your_trip"}

Answer (score 1):

Match url to controller#action and specify route name with `:as`:

```
get "your-trip/when-to-visit" => "your_trip#when_to_visit", :as => "when_to_visit"
```

Url helpers work too:

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
ruby-1.8.7-p302 :001 > app.when_to_visit_path
 => "/your-trip/when-to-visit"
```

Looks like with the help of [routing-filter gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) it might be possible write a custom route filter for hyphenated urls. That's of course an overkill for simple cases with just a couple of static pages.

**Your version with tiny modification works:**

```
controller :your_trip, :path => 'your-trip', :as => :your_trip do
  get "when_to_visit", :path => 'when-to-visit', :as => :when_to_visit
  get "booking_a_trip", :path => 'booking-a-trip', :as => :booking_a_trip
end
```

**Routes are then named as:**

```
your_trip_when_to_visit
your_trip_booking_a_trip
```